# Table view's endUpdates() method behaves differently in iOS 11

Tags: uitableview, ios10, ios11, reuseidentifier

I have a logic regarding the content in the cells of a `UITableView` where at some point I call `tableView.endUpdates()`. The behavior of my scenario was the expected in `iOS 10`, but now in `iOS 11` I am seeing that is behaving in a different way.

In `iOS 10`, user taps a cell, then I perform some logic and when `tableView.endUpdates()` is called, then `tableView(_cellForRowAt:)` is called once (at this point, 3 cells are shown in the screen and only one is being reused).

In `iOS 11`, user taps the cell (at this point, same 3 cells are shown in the screen), and after `tableView.endUpdates()` is called, `tableView(_cellForRowAt:)` is called 3 times. This is causing a behavior that it is not suitable for me.

Has somebody experienced an issue like this? How could I do in `iOS 11` if I want to "refresh" the content only of the cell the user has tapped?

Comment: Same is happening to me ... did you find any solution to this problem?, when I end updates, it builds all my cells and destroys my animations